# How to quickly change variable names in Vim?

Tags: vim, variables, refactoring

I am using Vim to read through a lot of C and Perl code containing many single letter variable names.

It would be nice to have some command to change the name of a variable to something more meaningful while I’m in the process of reading the code, so that I could read the rest of it faster.

Is there some command in Vim which could let me do this quickly?

I don’t think regexes would work because:

1. the same single letter name might have different purposes in different scoping blocks; and
2. the same combination of letters could be part of another longer variable name, a string literal, or a comment.

Are there any known solutions?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

The following is how to rename a variable which is defined in the current scope `{}`.

1. Move your cursor to the variable usage.
2. Press `gd`. Which means - move the cursor to the definition.
3. Now Press `[{` - this will bring you to the scope begin.
4. Press `V` - will turn on Visual Line selection.
5. Press `%` - will jump to the opposite `}` and thus will select the whole scope.
6. Press `:s/` - start of the substitute command.
7. `<C-R>/` - will insert a pattern that matches the variable name (that name you were on before pressing `gd`).
8. `/newname/gc<CR>` - will initiate search and replace with confirmation on every match.

Now you have to record a macro or even better - map a key.

Here are the final mappings:

```
" For local replace
nnoremap gr gd[{V%::s/<C-R>///gc<left><left><left>

" For global replace
nnoremap gR gD:%s/<C-R>///gc<left><left><left>
```

Put this to your `.vimrc` or just execute.
After this pressing `gr` on the local variable will bring you to `:s` command where you should enter `new_variable_name` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: +1 for learning more than 5 new Vim tricks I should have known before. Thanks

Comment: Really useful, +1 specially since it can be "extended" to other languages easily.

Comment: Note: gd doesn't work to locate the variable in the immediate scope of definition in Javascript mode in macvim. It takes me to the first use of the variable name in some function in the file :(

If you're within some scope and want to select that scope, "va{" - "visual select around {" - is the way to go I think.

Comment: A slightly improved version: https://gist.github.com/048616a2e3f5d1b5a9ad prompts user, shows old name, restores cursor position after replace

Comment: +1 very good vimgineering (I think I just coined a new term). Note: I actually needed to press colon (`:`) twice. The first time I pressed it, I saw `:'<,'>`. If I just typed `s/` from there it didn't work; I had to type another colon before the `s/`.

Comment: If you use [vim-textobj-indent](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-indent), then you can rename within the scope of the variable instead of the scope of the function: `nmap gr 1gdvai:s/<C-R>///gc<left><left><left>`. However, it requires nmap since it's using the vai map. Not sure if there's a way around that.

Comment: The local replace works only if I remove one of the colon before the s (::s -> :s). I've seen that someone edited the answer to add the second colon and I wonder why he did that...

Comment: Every vim related answer should be like this. Thanks for the tips man.

Comment: For dummies like me, please don't be confused by `<C-R>/` and `<CR>`. The first one is literally `ctrl`+`r` and then press `/`. The second one just means `enter`. Check `:help key-notation` for further reading.

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev : how do I defined scope for python code. (indentation is used for block)

Comment: The final mappings do not work for me as expected when the cursor is already at the definition.

For example: If the cursor is at `int foo = 5;`, refactoring with the final mapping 'gr' or 'gR' does not work. While refactoring with the cursor at `foo = 10;` with the final mapping 'gr' or 'gR' does work. Refactoring with manually entering the expression does work regardless of cursor position.

Comment: Note you don't need `<C-R>` in the substitute command, simply omitting the search will cause vim to use the last searched pattern, which in this case was created from the `gd` command.

So simply doing `:s//<newname>/gc` will suffice.

Comment: So much useful information here. Thanks for the thorough explanation @Mykola

Comment: but what is <C-R>?

Comment: shouldn't we just use a plugin instead of this?

Answer (score 48):

*I know it's an old question, and @mykola-golubyev's way obviously IS the best answer for the particular case in the OP question (which, I assume is going through obfuscated code where you're likely to have multiple blocks with same var names); but with the question name like that many people coming here from google searches probably look for less situation-specific ways to rename variables in VIM -- and those can be more concise*

I'm surprised no one suggested this way:

> **`*` `:s//`** *NEWNAME* **`/gc`**

The `*` is the same as `gn` - search the next occurrence of the word under the cursor AND make it the **last searched pattern**; you can then omit the search pattern in the substitute command and VIM will assume that last one is the pattern to search for.

For small amounts of var copies, here's an even quicker one:

> **`*` `cw`** *NEWNAME* **`<esc>`** then repeat **`n.`** for other occurrences

`*` is *search for occurrences*, `cw` is *change word*, `n` goes to the next occurrence of the last searched term and `.` repeats the last command (which is now *change word to NEWNAME*)

(Credits for me knowing all this go to [@doomedbunnies on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1zvks1/best_way_to_rename_variable_in_several_spots_in_a/))

Another cool trick: ([credits to @nobe4](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8288))

> **`*` `cgn`** *NEWNAME* **`<esc>`** then repeat **`.`** for other occurrences

`cgn` is "change whatever is the result of (find next occurrence)". Now that this is the **last command**, you don't need the `n` to go to the next occurrence, so fewer strokes again, and, more importantly, no need to alternate `n` and `.`. But, obviously, this one has the drawback of not having a way to skip an occurrence.

Here are some benefits of these over other similar approaches, or language-specific plugins with refactoring support:

- no command mapping, no fiddling with .vimrc(or init.vim), so you can use it in any VIM copy you come across (e.g. a quick task on some VPS or your friend's machine where configuring VIM your way would defeat the purpose of 'quick')
- using `*` or `gn` for word selection is very quick -- just one keystroke (well, let's say 1.5)
- using `*` or `gn` makes sure you don't get any matches inside other words, just as `:%s/<C-R>//gc` does. Beats typing the `:%s/\<OLDNAME\>/NEWNAME/gc` by hand: I personally tend to forget to use the `\<` things to limit matches to whole words only.
- Not using a scope will only result in a few extra strokes of `n` to skip unwanted matches -- probably even fewer than the extra strokes needed to limit the scope to a certain code block. Under normal circumstances, your variables are most likely somewhat localised to a certain code block anyway.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, there is no actual refactoring support in VIM.  When doing a rename with the intent of a refactor I usually take the following precautions:

1. Limit the scope of the change my using marks.
2. When entering the regex, bracket the name with \< and >.  This will make it match an entire word which reduces the types of incorrect renames that will occur.
3. Don't do a multiline replace to reduce chances of a bad replace
4. Look through the code diff carefully if it's anything other than a small change.

My end change looks something like this

```
:'a,'bs/\<foo\>/bar
```

I would love to be wrong about there not being a refactoring tool for VIM but I haven't seen it.

Comment: In Perl you can also add the type to the search pattern.  i.e. $ for scalars, @ for arrays, % for hashes

Comment: @Nathan: unfortunately, it's a bit more difficult in Perl (5.X), as the sigil of arrays and hashes changes with the usage: %hash -> whole hash, $hash{key} -> single value, @hash{qw/a b/} hash slice.

Answer (score 8):

Put this in your .vimrc

```
" Function to rename the variable under the cursor
function! Rnvar()
  let word_to_replace = expand("<cword>")
  let replacement = input("new name: ")
  execute '%s/\(\W\)' . word_to_replace . '\(\W\)/\1' . replacement . '\2/gc'
endfunction
```

Call it with `:call Rnvar()`

`expand("<cword>")` gets the word under the cursor. The search string uses `%` for file-scope, and the `\(\W\)` patterns look for non-word characters at the boundary of the word to replace, and save them in variables `\1` and `\2` so as to be re-inserted in the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the 'c' modifier in the global search and replace that would ask you for confirmation for each replace. It would take longer but it might work for a non-humongous code file:

```
%s/\$var/\$foo/gc
```

The c stands for confirm.

Comment: The i stands for ignore-case.  You want c, confirm every change.

Comment: oops.. sorry about that.. Fixed the answer

Comment: Answer still not fixed completely ;)

Comment: did you mean the escaped $? That's something that's kind of a personal preference of mine. $ works without escape and also with and since in the regex world and in vi $ has special meaning, I like to escape it just for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In c, you may be able to make some progress using cscope.  It makes an attempt at understanding syntax, so would have a chance of knowing when the letter was a variable.

Answer (score -1):

If this is across multiple files, you may consider taking a look at sed. Use find to grab your files and xargs plus sed for a replace. Say you want to replace a with a_better_name in all files matching *.c, you could do

find . -name "*.c" | xargs sed -i -e 's/a/a_better_name/g'

Bear in mind that this will replace ALL occurrences of a, so you may want a more robust regex.