# Python: how to batch rename mixed case to lower case with underscores

Tags: python, variables, ide, refactoring, naming-conventions

I've written a fair bit of my first significant Python script. I just finished reading PEP 8, and I learned that lower_case_with_underscores is preferred for instance variable names. I've been using mixedCase for variable names throughout, and I'd like my code to be make more Pythonic by changing those to lower_case_with_underscores if that's how we do things around here.

I could probably write some script that searches for mixedCase and tries to smartly replace it, but before I potentially reinvent the wheel, my question is whether a solution for that already exists, either within a Python-savvy editor or as a standalone application; or whether there's another approach that would accomplish the task of converting all mixedCase variable names to lower_case_with_underscores. I have searched a fair bit for a solution but didn't turn up anything. Any technique that specifically would yield this result would be appreciated.

Comment: What you need is an IDE with refactoring features (you need to change your tags, or at least add some as like as "ide"). Eclipse does this (cursor on the variable, shift+alt+r), vim can do this (sorry it's for perl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597687/changing-variable-names-in-vim), which editor do you use?

Comment: I'm currently using BBEdit for OS X, which is a fine editor but is not a proper IDE and has no special Python smarts beyond syntax coloring. Good suggestion to change tags -- do you have any opinion as to whether Eclipse or vim would be better for this particular task?

Comment: I don't claim eclipse or vim or BBedit or whatever editor is a better editor, but You could start here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments and pick one with the refactoring feature (eg PyCharm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted using GNU sed:

```
sed -i -e :loop -re 's/(^|[^A-Za-z_])([a-z0-9_]+)([A-Z])([A-Za-z0-9_]*)'\
'([^A-Za-z0-9_]|$)/\1\2_\l\3\4\5/' -e 't loop' myFile.py
```

It finds every instance of mixedCase -- but not CapitalWords, so class names are left intact -- and replaces it with lower_case_with_underscores; e.g. myVariable becomes my_variable, but MyClass remains MyClass.

(On an unrelated note, now that I've done it, I think I prefer the appearance of mixedCase over lower_case_with_underscores. The appearance of so many underscores all over my code is weird. But I'll do things the Python Way and see if I get used to it, particularly if I intend for my code to be seen or worked with by others; or maybe I'll do it the way I like and I've now got a simple way of converting it to the PEP 8 way if I intend to make the code public.)

Comment: As I write more code, I found that lower_case_with_underscore is more beautiful than mixedCase in python. (In my C/C++ cod I will stick to mixedCases). Thanks for your solution.