# How to renames variable according to the type

Tags: c, vim, refactoring

I need to get a way to do/find a vim script that would change a variable name according to a pattern!

Here is an answer that can help helping
[How to quickly change variable names in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597687/changing-variable-names-in-vim)

It would check which type is the variable and add a specific prefix

For example:

`char myvar` to `char char_myvar`

`char *myvar` to `char pointer_char_myvar`

or if the variable is a param to a function

`f(char myvar)` to `f(char param_char_myvar)`

those kind of markers will be defined by a pattern matching

The idea seem to go to the variable definition with `gd`, save it in register then take in another register the four words before (because in `char *myvar`, `*` count like a word and we need enough info to know if its in a function), check which pattern match (check which type, check if in a function or local) and then add markers.

Also how to apply this script to all variable?

But I'm failing hard.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you really want to do such silly things, don't forget to rename functions as well: `char char_myFunc(char char_myChar);` and don't forget `structs`: `struct x struct_x_myFunc (struct x struct_x_myStruct);` and `unions` and `enums` (now it gets really silly...)

Comment: Oh yeah, function are renamed like that too
`char function_char_myFunc(char char_myChar);`

Comment: @tofro You have been troll cancel.

Comment: Same for struct also, thx for thinking about it :D. Its silly but its required.

Comment: How big is the code in question? Does it follow some strict coding style with declarations all being of the same form? Does it have some tricky type declarations like functions returning functions?

Comment: Code is one file size (2k for the moment), no tricky stuff like that. and yes all declaration are the same form : declared in function param or at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a really stupid thing to do. It's even worse than sys hungarian notation -- on the subject check the decade old [article/post](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) from Joel Spolsky. (It could be eye opening in your environment)

Anyway. In [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) i've a few functions able to extract types or to tell when a type is actually a pointer, or const, etc. I also have functions that decode function signatures. It's in the autoload/lh/cpp directory of the plugin. It may depend on other functions from lh-dev.

Then you'll have to detect all variable declarations (universal-ctags or cscope will help here) and then rename all their occurrences.

Honestly you'd better proceed with libclang to refactor your code.

More precisely, as finding the exact functions is not trivial as these parts of my plugins is not documented:

- `echo lh#dev#c#function#_analyse_parameter('char *str')` will decompose a variable declaration,
- `echo lh#dev#c#types#is_pointer(lh#dev#c#function#_analyse_parameter('char *str').type)` will well you whether the type behind the variable is actually a pointer. NB: It doesn't support stuff like multiple declarations per line `char *s, c;`
- Given the line number where a function is declared, `:echo lh#dev#c#function#get_prototype(linenr, 0)` will extract the function prototype that can be analysed with `lh#cpp#AnalysisLib_Function#AnalysePrototype(the_protoype)`, there you'll have the function return type, its name, and the list of all its parameters (type, name, plus other info).
- I also have a `lh#dev#get_variables()` function that returns all the local variables ctags is able to identify within a range of lines -- this requires my lh-tags plugin.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you. I've given hints to work on to a solution.

Comment: Your plugin seem really usefull to masterize. I didnt find how to extract types and do what i wanted to do (only :DOX seemed to use type extraction functions)
I wish I had more time to learn to use it.
I did came up with my own vimscript solution

Comment: It's well hidden within lh-dev. I've edited my message to give more precise indications