# select the same words in the Vim

Tags: vim

I know there is a lot of information on how to do it, but I can't do it anyway. I use vs with vim expansion.

I have text with variables, I want to select for example variable `btn` in all text and change it to `button`. How can I do it?

I tried with select and press key **n**,
but it selects all text until next `btn;` 
also '*' is not working, it's just jumping to next `btn;`

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing variable names in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597687/changing-variable-names-in-vim)

Comment: For renaming variables in Visual Studio (is that what you mean with vs?), I would not use search and replace but rather use the builtin Visual Studio rename refactoring (CTRL+R, CTRL+R if you have the default keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: nope) vim changed many of them, so ctrl+r not working, mb later i change it in settings but for now i use my method. TY!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `*`or `viw` to visually select the word under the cursor.

Answer (score -1):

Found a good solution:

```
:%s/oldText/newText/g
```

more **here**: [https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/vi-vim-editor-search-and-replace-examples/](http://%20https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/vi-vim-editor-search-and-replace-examples/)